# In Scala, is it possible for me to dynamically specify the type parameter of a parametric type?

Tags: scala, types, parametric-polymorphism

I am writing a program where the user specifies the path to a class on the command line. I turn it into a `Class` object via:

```
val clazz = Class.forName(args([0]))
```

I have a parametric class `MyParametric[T]` with a single type parameter. I then want to make *another* `Class` type `Class[ParamatricType[clazz]` so I can pass that to a method, e.g. I want to do something like

```
myMethod(classOf[ParametricType[clazz]])
```

but that is not allowed. How can I instantiate a parametric type with the type parameter being given dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it as the argument to `classOf`, you don't even need the type parameter. You can just use `_`, because type parameters are erased at run-time in Scala:

```
myMethod(classOf[ParametricType[_]])
```

Answer (score 1):

`ParametricType`'s type parameter will be erased, so the value of `classOf[ParametricType[_]]` will be the same no matter what you plug in for `_` (including `_`).

The *type* won't be the same of the `classOf` won't be the same as that isn't erased (the compiler keeps track at compile time).  You could refer to the singleton type `clazz.type`, but it's not clear what that will buy you.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you provided it's hard to tell whether the user will specify from the set of known classes (e.g. fruits) or any class imaginable. However, you could use pattern matching with different classes during the assignment and handle that according to the type.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do something more than `classOf` (which the other answers already handle) and can modify `ParametricType`, one approach would be (depending on the details of what you actually need):

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
class ParametricType[T](implicit val tag: ClassTag[T])

val clazz: Class[_] = ...
myMethod(new ParametricType()(ClassTag(clazz)))
```